# Why raw socket sendto() function fails with 10022?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcp

I am developing a protocol fuzzer for ICMP, TCP, UDP and so on under VS2010. I have successfully sent out the ICMP and UDP packets by the raw socket interface. But I encountered a problem when sending TCP.

My environment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64, Administrator account.

Here is my way:

1) construct the transport header and data by myself.

2) use the raw socket for the IPv4 header and below. RawConnect() function is used to create such a raw socket. strIP is an IP address, and strProtocol is the IP protocol number need to be specified (like ICMP is 1, IGMP is 2, TCP is 6, UDP is 17). Because I didn't construct the IP header myself (m_bSelfConstructIPHeader = FALSE), so the IP protocol number is necessary. I didn't know if I used it right or not?

3) use sendto() function to send the buffer, which returns -1, and WSAGetLastError() returns 10022 which means "An invalid argument was supplied."

Below is the code, thx!

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "AFRawSocket.h"

#define IP_HDRINCL 2

AFRawSocket::AFRawSocket()
{
    m_socket = NULL;
    m_bSelfConstructIPHeader = FALSE;
}

CString AFRawSocket::itos(int i)
{
    CString strTemp;
    strTemp.Format(_T("%d"), i);
    return strTemp;
}

int AFRawSocket::stoi(CString s)
{
    return _wtoi(s);
}

//
// CStringAתCStringW
//
CStringW AFRawSocket::CStrA2CStrW(const CStringA &cstrSrcA)
{
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, LPCSTR(cstrSrcA), -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t *wstr = new wchar_t[len];
    memset(wstr, 0, len*sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, LPCSTR(cstrSrcA), -1, wstr, len);
    CStringW cstrDestW = wstr;
    delete[] wstr;

    return cstrDestW;
}

//
// CStringWתCStringA
//
CStringA AFRawSocket::CStrW2CStrA(const CStringW &cstrSrcW)
{
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, LPCWSTR(cstrSrcW), -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char *str = new char[len];
    memset(str, 0, len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, LPCWSTR(cstrSrcW), -1, str, len, NULL, NULL);
    CStringA cstrDestA = str;
    delete[] str;

    return cstrDestA;
}

void AFRawSocket::SetSelfConstructIPHeader(BOOL bSelfConstructIPHeader)
{
    m_bSelfConstructIPHeader = bSelfConstructIPHeader;
}

BOOL AFRawSocket::RawConnect(CString strIP, CString strProtocol)
{
    int optval;
    CStringA straIP = CStrW2CStrA(strIP);

    int iProtocol;
    if (strProtocol == _T("N/A"))
    {
        iProtocol = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        iProtocol = stoi(strProtocol);
    }

    sockaddr_in mysock;
    ZeroMemory((char*)&mysock,sizeof(mysock));//初始化
    mysock.sin_family=AF_INET;
    mysock.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(straIP);

    //Create Raw TCP Packet
    //printf("\nCreating Raw TCP Socket...");
    //ETH_P_ALL
    //AF_PACKET

//  if (iProtocol == IPPROTO_TCP)
//  {
//      iProtocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
//  }

    if((m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, iProtocol/*IPPROTO_RAW*/))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //printf("Creation of raw socket failed.");
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("RawConnect"));
        return FALSE;
    }
    //printf("Raw TCP Socket Created successfully.");
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (m_bSelfConstructIPHeader)
    {
        //Put Socket in RAW Mode.
        //printf("\nSetting the socket in RAW mode...");
        if(setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&optval, sizeof(optval))==SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            //printf("failed to set socket in raw mode.");
            MyMessageBox_Error(_T("RawConnect"));
            return FALSE;
        }
        //printf("Successful.");
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }


//  //Target Hostname
//  printf("\nEnter hostname : ");
//  gets(host);
//  printf("\nResolving Hostname...");
//  if((server=gethostbyname(host))==0)
//  {
//      printf("Unable to resolve.");
//      return 0;
//  }
    ZeroMemory(&m_dest, sizeof(m_dest));
    m_dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //m_dest.sin_port   = htons(0);  //your destination port
    m_dest.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(straIP);
    //m_dest.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8");
    //m_dest.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("202.112.128.50");
    //memcpy(&m_dest.sin_addr.s_addr,&mysock.sin_addr.s_addr,4);
    //printf("Resolved.");
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

//  if (bind(m_socket, (SOCKADDR *) &m_dest, sizeof(m_dest)) < 0)
//  {
//      int iError = WSAGetLastError();
//      MyMessageBox_Error(_T("RawConnect"));
//      return FALSE;
//  }

    return TRUE;
}

void AFRawSocket::RawSend(LPBYTE lpBuffer, DWORD dwSize)
{
    int iRet = sendto(m_socket , (const char *) lpBuffer, dwSize, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&m_dest, sizeof(m_dest));
    //if (iRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
    if (iRet <= 0)
    {
        //printf("Error sending Packet : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        int iError  =WSAGetLastError();
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("RawSend"));
    }
}

void AFRawSocket::RawDisconnect()
{
    if (m_socket)
    {
        closesocket(m_socket);
        m_socket = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very few versions of Windows supports Raw Sockets, please check that first.

Comment: thx, but I am the administrator for my Win7 ultimate, meantime I successfully sent the "self construct Ip header", UDP and ICMP, only TCP fails, so can we suppose the Raw Sockets are supported?

Comment: As per I know, and I may be wrong, Windows started supporting Raw sockets in WinXp and kept it till WinXP SP2, still drivers like WinPCAP can use it, but I am not sure in user space.

Comment: can you make doubly sure that your `m_dest` hasn't gotten corrupted at some point by hardcode-recreating the structure just before the call to `sendto`?

Comment: @hsluoyz You may refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740463(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MrDuk I am sure m_dest isn't modified between RawConnect() and RawSend()

Comment: @pranitkothari OK, that's the right reason I think, is there any workaround? I know the WinPcap can send packets too, but it's so inconvenient for me to build a packet from ethernet?

Comment: @hsluoyz I really don't know much details, but you may use WinPcap as library in your application.