# `sendto` failed with 10022 error code when sending raw packets on Win10-x64

Tags: c++, winsock, raw-sockets, libtins

I'm developing application for scanning opening ports with [libtins](https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins), but I got error (10022 - WSAEINVAL) when sending raw packet. Here is my minimal test code, which will print **Send failed** immediately meaning no response(just because WSAEINVAL error happens inside `libtins`):

```cpp
void sendSynPacket()
{
  Tins::PacketSender sender;
  Tins::IP pkt = Tins::IP(IPv4Address("172.18.0.3")) / Tins::TCP(20001, 30000);

  pkt.rfind_pdu<Tins::TCP>().set_flag(Tins::TCP::SYN, 1);
  std::unique_ptr<Tins::PDU> response(sender.send_recv(pkt));
  if(response)
  {
    if(response->rfind_pdu<Tins::TCP>().flags() == (Tins::TCP::SYN|Tins::TCP::ACK))
      std::cout << "open " << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << "close " << std::endl;
  }
  else
    std::cout << "Send failed" << std::endl;
}
```

System info:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎11/‎21/‎2023
OS build    22621.2715
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22677.1000.0
```

Besides, destination ip("172.18.0.3") and port(20001) is known opening port and reachable. and I have searched a lot and find no solutions, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573652/why-raw-socket-sendto-function-fails-with-10022) . I find some important things related to my problem, like:

1. Run as administrator;
2. Check if my computer enabling `RAW socket` by ***WSAEnumProtocols***,`netsh winsock show catalog`, and I get some logs contain "MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP]" in description filed, so it is enabled, right?
3. Close all firewall;
4. Check source codes within `libtins`, no obvious incorrect codes found

What did I missed? Or just because my platform  doesn't support raw socket, if so, is there any way to make work done on my laptop?